# Create external HIVE table from files with different record formats

Tags: hive, external, hdfs

I would like to create an external HIVE table that utilizes data already in HDFS.  The files are in a directory like `/hdfs/data/location` and sub directories with the `year-month` format.  ex: `/hdfs/data/location/2013-december` and `/hdfs/data/location/2014-january`.

Within these directories are multiple files but within the files are different types of data (different fields).  Examples of the different types of records are:

Type A

```
type
state
city
population
```

Type B

```
type
zipcode
registeredvoters
```

Actual data example (tab delimited)

```
type:A   state:New York  city:New York    population:8336697
type:A   state:California  city:Los Angeles population:3857799
type:B   zipcode:92118  registeredvoters:794051
type:B   zipcode:92155  registeredvoters:794053
type:A   state:Illinois    city:Chicago population:2714856
```

The data is already in this format and being used by other processes outside of HIVE, so changing it may not be an option.  I would also not want to duplicate the data in HDFS.

**Is there a way to create a HIVE table for only a given type as defined in the data above?**

Here is what I have so far for the create:

```
create external table population (
  type string,
  state string,
  city string,
  population int
)
location '/hdfs/data/location';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can have a table, but I think you could make a view, interpreting the line using the str_to_map UDF

```
create external table raw_population( line string ) location '/hdfs/data/location';

create view population_view as
select
    pmap['type'] as type,
    pmap['state'] as state,
    pmap['city'] as city
    pmap['population'] as population
from 
  ( select str_to_map( line, '\t', ':') as pmap from raw_population ) pm;
```

Comment: I would also need the where type='A' since type='B' does not have those columns?

Comment: You can add other columns from the other type , ( ie. pmap['zipcode'] , pmap['population'] ) and it should return null if the value isn't in the map.

Or you can add " pmap['type'] = 'A' " as well